# Passing variables via URL

Tags: php, variables

Is there way to pass variable via URL?
Becouse I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<a href="/testy-aparatury/przypomnienie-o-testach/formularz/form/3-wprowadz-aparat&id=18">
```

but it won't work (trying to pass id)

Comment: Please post the code you use to get the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a question mark to start a query string; the ampersand is used to separate parameters.

```
.../form/3-wprowadz-aparat?id=18
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

In PHP, variables in the query string are GET parameters, available from the globally-scoped associative array [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).